# parsing json data through url in js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse data from a JSON url link. I'm confused how to get my js to read the array and put into a canvas tag to create a bar graph. I only want to use js and not jQuery. Here's my code with comment notes. Here's the JSON:

`[{ "title":"Random Information", "item01":"29", "item02":"41", "item03":"7", "item04":"42", "item05":"11" }]`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>barchart</title>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

//var arr = [20, 40, 50, 100, 150]; the barchart shows up with set array

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://myurl";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var x = 20
var y = 300
var width = 50
var height;
var arr = [];

function myFunction(arr) {
var out = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
out += arr[i].label;
}

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = out;
}

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(x,y-arr[0],width, arr[0]); //should this be arr[0].value  to control height of bar - didn't work
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText(arr[0], x+15, y+25); //should this be arr[0].label to show the title of the bar - didn't work

ctx.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
ctx.fillRect(x+55, y-arr[1], width, arr[1]);
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText(arr[1], x+70, y+25);

ctx.fillStyle = "#32cd32";
ctx.fillRect(x+110, y-arr[2], width, arr[2]);
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText(arr[2], x+125, y+25);

ctx.fillStyle = "#ff9933";
ctx.fillRect(x+165, y-arr[3], width, arr[3]);
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText(arr[3], x+170, y+25);

ctx.fillStyle = "#f3f315";
ctx.fillRect(x+220, y-arr[4], width, arr[4]);
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText(arr[4], x+230, y+25);

ctx.stroke()
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="550" style="border: 1px     solid #d3d3d3;"> Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas  tag</canvas>
<div id = "data"></div>
</body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: `label` and `value` don't appear in your JSON, so they will be undefined.

Comment: `out` doesn't exist outside of your `myFunction` function.  You need to do all code relating to `out` *inside* that function.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that you provided only has one object in it. And that Object has item01-item04 in it.

Consider using a json like this:

```
{
    "title": "Random Information",
    "data": [29, 41, 7, 42, 11]
}
```

In this case, `arr.data` is the real array that you need.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand that all my information would be called with arr[0] and now have applied it to my code by adding - item01 = arr[0].item01;

Answer (score 0):

Your `myFunction()` method does to seem to expect the same data structure that is being passed, which is an single member array, holding your object. Why then would one try to loop over the wrapping array?

That object itself has no property called `label`, so you will always get empty string concatentated to `out` variable.